# Geodjango PostgreSQL/PostGIS database question

Tags: python, openlayers-2, python-2.7, geodjango, django

I have a simple django app using sqlite3. My app is simple I have django user authentication system where the user can be upload spatial raster images and can see that images in user personal HTML page filter by use id.

Here is my model :

```
class nomodel(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    upload = models.ImageField(upload_to=user_directory_path)
```

sqlite3 database :

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

But that way is not GIS way to work with leaflet to add this raster in open layers.

If I change my code to :

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models

class testRaster(models.Model):
    raster_id = models.TextField(primary_key=True, default=1)
    name = models.TextField(default='test_layer')
    raster = models.RasterField()
    #user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    #raster = models.RasterField(upload_to=user_directory_path)


DATABASES = {
    'default': {
         'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
         'NAME': 'geodjango',
         'USER': 'geo',
    },
}
```

but my question is because never use `PostGIS` in the past is in `sqlite3` in `upload` field save the image path from my `nomodel` model but in the `raster`  field from `testRaster` model save again the path of images ?

in `testRaster` ant `PostGIS` database can I use again `user authentication` like `sqlite3` model ?